# Validation form with ajax cannot go through the If statement, just only go through else statement

Tags: javascript, php

```html
<?php
    //session_start();
    include_once '../controller/config.php';
    
    
    /* $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];
    
    print_r ("User name:    ".$user);
    print_r("\r");
    print_r ("Pasword:    ".$pass);
    print_r("\r");
    print_r("\r");
    print_r("\r"); */
    
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
    {
        $user1 = $_POST['username'];
        $pass1 = $_POST['password'];
        
        /* print_r ("User name inside:    ".$user);
        print_r("\r");
        print_r ("Pasword inside:    ".$pass);
        print_r("\r");
        print_r("\r");
        print_r("\r"); */
        
        $queryLogin = "SELECT COUNT(id) as name, password FROM web.account WHERE name=:user AND password=:passWD";
        $stmtLogin = $sqlConWeb->prepare($queryLogin);
        $stmtLogin->bindValue(":user", $user1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtLogin->bindValue(":passWD", md5($pass1), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtLogin->execute();
        
        $fetchInfo = $stmtLogin->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        
        $checkInfo = $fetchInfo['name'];
        
        /* print_r($fetchInfo);
        print_r("\r");
        print_r("\r"); */
        
        //print_r($checkInfo);
        
        //if($user1 == ""){
            
        //}
        
        if($user1 == ""){
            echo 'user_empty';
        }elseif(strlen($user1) <= 4){
            echo 'min_user_not_enough';
        }elseif($pass1 == ""){
            echo 'pass_empty';
        }elseif(strlen($pass1) <= 4){
            echo 'min_pass_not_enough';
        }else{
            echo 'success';
        }
        
    }
    
?>
```

and this one is the javascript file for validation form on client side.

```js
/*
    This is the js file for validate form code by Vinh Doan
    
    
*/

function LoginForm(){
    
    var userName = jQuery('#username').val();
    var passwd = jQuery('#password').val();
    var errorMess = '';
    
    /* if(userName == ""){
        document.getElementById("username").style.border = "1px solid red";
        errorMess = "yes";
    }else if(userName.trim().length < 0 ){
        jQuery('#error-message').html('* Tên tài khoản không được ít hơn 5 ký tự!');
        errorMess = 'yes';
    }
    
    if(passwd == ""){
        document.getElementById("password").style.border = "1px solid red";
        errorMess = "yes";
    }else if(passwd.trim().length < 0 ){
        jQuery('#error-message').html('* Mật khẩu không được ít hơn 5 ký tự!');
        errorMess = 'yes';
    } */
    
    if(errorMess == ''){
        
        $.ajax({
            url: '/login.html',
            type: 'post',
            data: 'username='+userName+'&password='+passwd,
            success: function (result) {
                //alert(result);
                
                console.log(result);
                
                if(result == "user_empty"){
                    jQuery('#error-message').html('* User name is empty!');
                }else if(result == "min_user_not_enough"){
                    jQuery('#error-message').html('* Username cannot less than 4 characters!');
                }else if(result == "pass_empty"){
                    jQuery('#error-message').html('* Please fill out the password!');
                }else if(result == "min_pass_not_enough"){
                    jQuery('#error-message').html('* Password cannot less than 4 characters!');
                }else{
                    jQuery('#error-message').html('* Your login successful!');
                }
                
            }


        });
        
    }
    
    
}
```

The problem is when I try the submit button, the error cannot go into If statement, It was got into else statement, although the data from php file that I recieved was correct code.I don't know why that could not go into If statement. I also have a picture that recieved the code in console below.

can you guys help me figure out the problem. Thank you alot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Luog.png)

Comment: They way those console outputs are indented, it suggests that there is probably quite a bit of whitespace before them.

Comment: `data: 'username='+userName+'&password='+passwd,` - how this will cause problems, as soon as the username or password I enter contains f.e. a `&`, should be obvious.

Comment: @CBroe you mean secure on the input

Comment: @CBroe I did try this way to trim down the white spcae or something else: $.trim(result)  but that did not work too

Comment: trim doesn't modify the variable you passed, you need to actually assign the result again: `result = $.trim(result)`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//session_start();
include_once '../controller/config.php';


/* $user = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

print_r ("User name:    ".$user);
print_r("\r");
print_r ("Pasword:    ".$pass);
print_r("\r");
print_r("\r");
print_r("\r"); */


$pass_data="";

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
    $user1 = $_POST['username'];
    $pass1 = $_POST['password'];
    
    /* print_r ("User name inside:    ".$user);
    print_r("\r");
    print_r ("Pasword inside:    ".$pass);
    print_r("\r");
    print_r("\r");
    print_r("\r"); */
    
    $queryLogin = "SELECT COUNT(id) as name, password FROM web.account WHERE name=:user AND password=:passWD";
    $stmtLogin = $sqlConWeb->prepare($queryLogin);
    $stmtLogin->bindValue(":user", $user1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmtLogin->bindValue(":passWD", md5($pass1), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmtLogin->execute();
    
    $fetchInfo = $stmtLogin->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
    $checkInfo = $fetchInfo['name'];
    
    /* print_r($fetchInfo);
    print_r("\r");
    print_r("\r"); */
    
    //print_r($checkInfo);
    
    //if($user1 == ""){
        
    //}
    
    if($user1 == ""){
        $pass_data='user_empty';
    }elseif(strlen($user1) <= 4){
        $pass_data='min_user_not_enough';
    }elseif($pass1 == ""){
        $pass_data='pass_empty';
    }elseif(strlen($pass1) <= 4){
        $pass_data='min_pass_not_enough';
    }else{
        $pass_data='success';
    }
    
}

return $pass_data;
?>
```

your ajax---

```
if(errorMess == ''){
    
    $.ajax({
        url: '/login.html',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'username='+userName+'&password='+passwd,
        success: function (result) {
            //alert(result);
            
            console.log(result);

            if(result){
            
            if(result == "user_empty"){
                jQuery('#error-message').html('* User name is empty!');
            }else if(result == "min_user_not_enough"){
                jQuery('#error-message').html('* Username cannot less than 4 characters!');
            }else if(result == "pass_empty"){
                jQuery('#error-message').html('* Please fill out the password!');
            }else if(result == "min_pass_not_enough"){
                jQuery('#error-message').html('* Password cannot less than 4 characters!');
            }else{
                jQuery('#error-message').html('* Your login successful!');
            }
         }
            
        }


    });
    
}
```

Comment: hello try this code

Comment: Hi there, I did try It, but It still get the same problem, and when I check my console log, It did not pass the code into ajax

Comment: hi can i see the view (html) page?